# Cannot update one variable in recursive function

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to solve one problem using DFS:
Given a binary tree (not BST!) and a target, find the treenode value that is closest to the given target.
I know there're multiple ways to solve this problem, but I'm just trying to do a simple DFS to traverse through each node and update the min along the way, and then after all nodes have been visited, return min.

The problem I'm having right now is that the min I return in the closestValue() function is always the initial root.val, I've drawn out the recursive calls stack, it all works as expected, the min is always updated, but when it returns to the closestValue() function, the min is always set back to its initial root.val value, I'm puzzled with this.

Any help is deeply appreciated!

```
public int closestValue(TreeNode root, double target) {
    Integer min = root.val;
    Double minDelta = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    dfs(root, min, minDelta, target);
    return min;
}

private void dfs(TreeNode root, Integer min, Double minDelta, double target){
    if(root == null) return;
    if(minDelta > Math.abs(root.val - target)){
        minDelta = Math.abs(root.val - target);
        min = root.val;
    }
    dfs(root.left, min, minDelta, target);
    dfs(root.right, min, minDelta, target);
}
```

Comment: Your `closestValue` function never modifies `min` before returning it. You seem to have a basic misunderstanding of how pass-by-value works. Why not rewrite `dfs` so that it returns something?

Comment: Thanks a lot John! I know I must be misunderstanding something. But I don't understand why other recursive function could modify a variable, I'll paste another recursive function below. Also, I tried to return the min value in dfs() function, but it didn't work out.

Comment: Java is always pass-by-value. The value passed might be a reference to a mutable object, and mutable objects can be, well, mutated. But -- primitive values like `int` can never be modified by a function call, recursive or otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I totally understand Java is always pass-by-value. But what I don't understand is the below solution, how come its paths variable could be mutated? and even return in the end? What's the difference between the below one and my above recursive function? Also, I changed min to Integer type, still not working. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, I figured out, as John Coleman suggested, letting dfs() function return a value is a good way out:

```
public int closetValue(TreeNode root, double target){
    return dfs(root, target, root.val);
}

private int dfs(TreeNode root, double target, int minVal){
    if(root == null) return minVal;
    if(Math.abs(root.val - target) < Math.abs(minVal - target)){
        minVal = root.val;
    }
    minVal = dfs(root.left, target, minVal);
    minVal = dfs(root.right, target, minVal);
    return minVal;
}
```

The reason I had trouble returning a value was because I thought I need to do some processing after I get minVal from both left and right subtrees:

```
int leftMinVal = dfs(root.left, target, minVal);
int rightMinVal = dfs(root.left, target, minVal);
return Math.min(leftMinVal, rightMinVal);
```

which of course gives me wrong answer.
Thanks to the help.